# invoke function for each element in array

Tags: coffeescript

I have this code:

```
log.error(r.reason) for r in results when r.state == 'rejected'
```

which translates into:

```
var r, _i, _len, _results;
_results = [];
for (_i = 0, _len = results.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
  r = results[_i];
  if (r.state === 'rejected') {
    _results.push(log.error(r.reason));
  }
}
return _results;
```

I do not need to accumulate the results of `log.error`, I just need to print an error for each appropriate element of the array. How is this done in coffeescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost every statement in CoffeeScript is an expression. For loops, this implies accumulating the result of each iteration in an array. If you do not want that behavior, you must explicitly add a `return` statement:

```
log.error(r.reason) for r in results when r.state == 'rejected'; return
```

---

In addition, in order to answer to your question title: **"invoke function for each element in array"** if your JS runtime supports the array function [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), this is an alternative way to apply a function on every array item:

```
results.forEach (item) -> log.error item.reason if item.state == 'rejected'
```

Comment: thanks. map is what I am trying to avoid. because map collects the results of each function application.

Comment: Why would you use `map` when you're iterating rather than mapping? Wouldn't `results.filter(...).forEach(...)` make more sense if you're doing it with iterators?

Comment: @muistooshort I was editing my answer in that direction when you posted your comment. Of course `forEach` is the right answer.